# TortoiseGit - where is the reset option for a branch?

Tags: tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit 64 bit version on Windows 10. I know it has a reset option because the [documentation talks about it](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reset.html). However, I cannot find the menu option for "Reset". I have searched the preferences to see if it needed to be added but I cannot find it anywhere. Here is a screen capture of my TortoiseGit menu.

[image: My TortoiseGit menu]

Comment: I blame the documentation. It's out-of-date, as evidenced by your screenshoot versus the one at the link you provided.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Right now, the [reset dialog](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reset.html) can only be opened using the log dialog context menu.

[image: Context menu of log dialog]

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html

Comment: That is where is was hiding. Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is reset in log dialog..https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html

Comment: @RajaNagendraKumar It's a context menu, meaning you need to right-click on the target revision to reset to.

Comment: For anyone confused about this. Right-click on the folder, select TourtiseGit > Show Log. A dialog will appear listing all the commits. Right click on the commit you want to reset to, and that's when the above context menu will appear

Answer (score 1):

To add onto MrTux,

Go to the log dialog, right click on the commit you want to revert to and there should be a 'reset "current branch" to this' popup. If you want to clear all local changes in favor for this commit, then perform a Hard reset.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but couldn't figure it out from the answer here.

But the way I did it was, after I did a fetch there was the option to do a reset in the dropdown in the bottom corner of the dialog